# What is the independence number of hamming graph?

Tags: graph-theory

Hamming graph H(d,q) is  Cartesian product of d complete graphs Kq. We know the independence number of direct product of d complete graphs Kq. What is the independence number of hamming graph?

Answer (score 7):

I take the Hamming graph $H(d,q)$ to be the Cartesian product of $d$ copies of the complete graph $K_q$. Its independence number is $q^{d-1}$.

Proof: The Hamming graph lies in the Hamming scheme, so the clique-coclique bound holds: If $C$ is a clique and $S$ a coclique, then $|C||S|\ne n$, where $n$ is the number of vertices of the scheme - here $q^d$. Clearly we have cliques of size $q$, so $|S|\le q^{n-1}$. To get a coclique of the right size, view the vertices of $K_q$ as integers mod $q$ and let $S$ be the set of $d$-tuples whose coordinates sum to zero. Then no two $d$-tuples in $S$ differ in exactly one position, and so $S$ is a coclique.

Of course the clique-coclique bound is overkill here. The $d$-tuples with first $d-1$ coordinates zero form a subgroup of order $q$ in $Z_q^d$. Hence the cosets of this subgroup form a partition of the vertices of the Hamming graph into cliques of size $q$, and therefore $|S| \le q^{d-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

> The Hamming graph $H(n,d)$ has $2^n$ vertices labeled by the binary
>   vectors of length $n$, two vertices being joined by an edge if and
>   only if the Hamming distance between the corresponding vectors is at
>   least $d$. More generally $H_q(n,d)$ refers to $q^n$ vertices labeled
>   by $q$-ary vectors of length $n$.

- N.J.A. Sloane, Unsolved Problems in Graph Theory Arising from the Study of Codes (1989)

> The independence number $\alpha(H_q(n,d))$ of the Hamming graph
>   $H_q(n,d)$ is determined by the maximum number $N_q(n,s)$ of $q$-ary
>   sequences of length $n$ that intersect pairwise, i.e., have the same
>   entries, in at least $s=n-d+1$ positions.

- S. El Rouayheb and C.N. Georghiades, [Graph Theoretic Methods in Coding Theory](http://www.ece.iit.edu/~salim/docs/GTMICT.pdf) (2012)
- R. Ahlswede and L.H. Khachatrian [The Diametric Theorem in Hamming Spaces -- Optimal Anticodes](http://www.mathematik.uni-bielefeld.de/ahlswede/homepage/public/132.pdf) (1998)

You want the binary case $q=2$. Closed-form expressions for the number $N_q(n,s)$ exist, see cited references and Theorem 2 of

- P. Frankl and N. Tokushige, [The Erdos-Ko–Rado Theorem for Integer Sequences](http://www.cc.u-ryukyu.ac.jp/~hide/ekr.pdf) (1999)

Comment: What is $H_q(n,d)$ ? Classically, $H(n,d)$ is the graph on $n$-tuples of words in the alphabet of size $d$, with adjacency being having Hamming distance 1. 
And why $q=2$? Do you mean $q=1$?

Comment: Thank u carlo, but there is no any exact answer for this, am i right?

Comment: Hq(n; d), has as vertices
all the q-ary sequences of length n, and two vertices are adjacent if their
Hamming distance is larger or equal to d. So it will not represent classical hamming graph as q=2.

Comment: I added the definition of Hamming graph from coding theory, which my answer addressed. I guess there's more than one "Hamming graph"?

Comment: Ofcourse, In hamming graph, what I asked for, two vertices are adjacent if their hamming distance is 1. But in Hq(n,d) vertices are adjacent if their hamming distance is larger or equal to d.

Comment: @Carlo, I think you edited your answer at the same time as I wrote mine... So they've got basically the same content!

Answer (score 1):

Experiments suggest it might be $q^{d-1}$.

Here is data from sage:

```
d= 2 q= 2 alpha= 2 factor= 2  alpha - q^(d-1) 0
d= 2 q= 3 alpha= 3 factor= 3  alpha - q^(d-1) 0
d= 2 q= 4 alpha= 4 factor= 2^2  alpha - q^(d-1) 0
d= 2 q= 5 alpha= 5 factor= 5  alpha - q^(d-1) 0
d= 2 q= 6 alpha= 6 factor= 2 * 3  alpha - q^(d-1) 0
d= 3 q= 2 alpha= 4 factor= 2^2  alpha - q^(d-1) 0
d= 3 q= 3 alpha= 9 factor= 3^2  alpha - q^(d-1) 0
d= 3 q= 4 alpha= 16 factor= 2^4  alpha - q^(d-1) 0
d= 3 q= 5 alpha= 25 factor= 5^2  alpha - q^(d-1) 0
d= 3 q= 6 alpha= 36 factor= 2^2 * 3^2  alpha - q^(d-1) 0
d= 4 q= 2 alpha= 8 factor= 2^3  alpha - q^(d-1) 0
d= 4 q= 3 alpha= 27 factor= 3^3  alpha - q^(d-1) 0
d= 4 q= 4 alpha= 64 factor= 2^6  alpha - q^(d-1) 0
d= 4 q= 5 alpha= 125 factor= 5^3  alpha - q^(d-1) 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I did a google, and came up with this paper:

> *Graph Theoretic Methods in Coding Theory* by Salim El Rouayheb and Costas N. Georghiades

Let me quote from them.

> The independence number $\alpha(H_q(n;d))$ of the Hamming graph $H_q(n,d)$ is
>   actually the maximum number of sequences of length $n$
>   such that the Hamming distance between any two of them is at most
>   $d-1$. A set of sequences
>   satisfying this property is called an
>   *anticode*
>   with maximum distance
>   $d-1$.
>   Define $N_q(n,s)$ to be the maximum number of
>   $q$ -ary sequences of length
>   $n$
>   that intersect pairwise, i.e., have the same entries, in at least
>   $s$
>   positions.
>   It follows that
>   $$\alpha(H_q(n;d)) = N_q(n,t); \textrm{ with } t=n-d+1.$$

They go on to assert that a closed form for $N_q(n,t)$ can be found as the Diametric Theorem of this paper...

> R. Ahlswede and L. H. Khachatrian, *The Diametric Theorem in Hamming
>   Spaces - Optimal anticodes*,
>   Adv. in Appl. Math
>   , vol. 20, pp. 429-449, 1998.

... or as Theorem 2 of this paper

> P. Frankl and N. Tokushige, *The Erdos-Ko-Rado Theorem for Integer Se-quences*,"
>   Combinatorica
>   , vol. 19, pp. 55-63, 1999.

I can't access this second paper but I've looked at the first. Stating the closed form is a pain, so I won't do it here, but you should have a look.